# Xcode 13.4.1 fails to export localizations

Tags: swift, xcode

All of a sudden, when I try to export my localizations I get the message below! I really don't understand why! I ran `plutil -lint Localizable.strings` and I get `Localizable.strings: OK`.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Edit: It continues even after this change
[image]

Comment: check for invisible characters

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Editor -> Invisibles.
However, you can simply try to delete the entire line and write it again by hand.

Comment: I can't find anything! I rewrote it myself, but nothing changed! I even rolled back to a previous commit and it still didn’t work! Any other idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot advise from a screenshot. Try to create a minimal file with the problem and share it here?

Comment: I actually deleted all lines except one, and I got the exact same message! I think the issue has to be somewhere else, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Could you share the file with that single line then?

Comment: See the edit I just made

Comment: I am asking for the file, not a screenshot of the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246198/discussion-between-sotiris-kaniras-and-sulthan).

Comment: Here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr92vr2f00782mf/Localizable.strings?dl=0